# General procedure for maximizing a function f(x,y) where x and y are restricted to stay along a known path in the xOy plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus

**I am looking for a general procedure for maximizing a function f(x,y) where x and y are restricted to stay along a known path in the xOy plane**

In the xOy plane there is a set of points $(x_n, y_n)$, where n goes from $1$ to $N_{max}$. The numerical values of $x_n$, $y_n$ are known. If united by lines, or an interpolation curve, starting from $1$ and ending with $N_{max}$, these points form a path.

There is also a function $f(x,y)$ that is given as an analytical expression.

**Question:**
Find $x$ and $y$, along a given interpolation path which passes through the points $(x_n, y_n)$, that maximizes $f(x,y)$?

One problem I have is that I can not define $y=y(x)$ or $x=x(y)$ because the path can be like a spiral.

**Update:**

I understand that the problem can be solved by introducing a variable $t$ and finding two ordinary interpolation functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ that pass through the points $(n,x_n)$ and $(n,y_n)$, respectively. Once the two function are found, the initial $f(x,y)$ turns into a sigle variable function $f(x(t),y(t))$ where $t$ varies from $1$ to $n$. The initial problem reduces to finding the maximum of an one variable function.

Comment: The path is independent of the function $f(x,y)$. The path can be obtained in the most basic case by simply connecting the points with straight lines. The idea is that the path is given and it can not be modified.

Comment: thought you were optimizing in term of the interpolation path, but you only search along a curve the maximum of $f$, which is then a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ once you have parametrized your curve. so give an example because it should always be possible to parametrize a curve.

Comment: I added an update to my initial question to explain what I have understood from your answer.